# Reading Lisp objects from a string

Tags: string, common-lisp

I am familiar with the basic template for collecting the Lisp objects from a file, as in:

```
(with-open-file (stream "filename.lisp")
    (loop for object = (read stream nil 'eof)
          until (eq object 'eof)
          collect object))
```

But I'm not sure how to translate this into collecting the objects from a string, for example using `read-from-string`. Do you then have to keep track of the index where you left off in the string? Also, how do you avoid a name conflict with `eof` or any other legitimate Lisp object like `nil` or `t` in the input?

Comment: [WITH-INPUT-FROM-STRING](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_in_f.htm#with-input-from-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`with-input-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_in_f.htm#with-input-from-string) to read from a string.

To prevent a conflict with the `eof` symbol, you can use an uninterned symbol or some other object that's created dynamically.

```
(with-input-from-string (stream "this is a (list of 3 things)")
  (loop with eof-marker = '#:eof
        for object = (read stream nil eof-marker)
        until (eq object eof-marker)
        collect object))
```

Comment: In another answer, sds pointed out that some people typically use the stream object itself: `(read stream nil stream)`.

Comment: I get an undefined variable `#:eof`. Will everything still work properly with `(make-symbol "eof")`?

Comment: What I don't quite understand yet is that since the eof-marker is created before the string is read, why there couldn't be a variable conflict while reading from the string, for example while reading from "#:eof". Is it because the eof-marker is not interned?

Comment: Yes, it's because it's not interned. So it's not possible for the reader to return that same symbol -- every time it reads `#:eof` it creates a new, non-interned symbol.